# No bsoncxx for MongoDB C++ driver demo compilation

Tags: c++, mongodb

Hello， I want to compile some demo of mongodb-C++ API.

I follow the official guide:

http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/

It is OK for step 1-5.

For use custom bson and mongocxx, I run the additional command as recommend:

> In the event that you are building the BSON C++ library and/or the C++
>   driver to embed with other components and you wish to avoid the
>   potential for collision with components installed from a standard
>   build or from a distribution package manager, you can make use of the
>   BSONCXX_OUTPUT_BASENAME and MONGOCXX_OUTPUT_BASENAME options to cmake.

```
cmake ..                                            \
-DBSONCXX_OUTPUT_BASENAME=custom_bsoncxx        \
-DMONGOCXX_OUTPUT_BASENAME=custom_mongocxx
```

The mongo-db demo is used:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>

#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>

int main(int, char**) {
    mongocxx::instance inst{};
    mongocxx::client conn{mongocxx::uri{}};

    bsoncxx::builder::stream::document document{};

    auto collection = conn["testdb"]["testcollection"];
    document << "hello" << "world";

    collection.insert_one(document.view());
    auto cursor = collection.find({});

    for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
        std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I run with the command:

```
c++ --std=c++11 test.cpp -o test $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongocxx)
```

It feedbacks some error:

```
#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp
```

It looks like the header file has not been included.

How can I resolve the problem?

Thanks & Regards!

Comment: How can I link my installed mongodb-cxx API during the demo?

Comment: I run the compilation command again with the include library set right: c++ --std=c++11 test.cpp -o test     -DMONGOCXX_STATIC -DBSONCXX_STATIC -DMONGOC_STATIC -DBSON_STATIC     -I/include/libmongoc-1.0     -I/include/libbson-1.0     -I/opt/mongo-cxx-driver/include/mongocxx/v_noabi     -I/opt/mongo-cxx-driver/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi     -L/usr/local/lib -lmongocxx-static -lbsoncxx-static     -lmongoc-static-1.0 -lsasl2 -lssl -lcrypto -lbson-static-1.0 -lm -lpthread -v . Still problem

Comment: The error is: ld: library not found for -lmongocxx-static
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)